# Order by term not in result set

Tags: android, sqlite, union, android-sqlite

I am getting the following error while executing query in SQLite:

```
4th ORDER BY term does not match any column in the result set
```

My query:

```
select * from Users where deleted != 1 AND  DATE(created) <= '2013-10-09' and 
DATE(created) >= '2013-09-09T12:41:55.261Z' UNION select * from Users where deleted != 1 AND 
owner NOT IN(Select userid from Customer) 
order by Type DESC,License ASC,NUM ASC,"MCTD#" ASC,Name DESC;
```

However the equivalent with a single query i.e. **without the UNION** seems to work 
fine.

Is there any restriction that **ORDER BY** terms must be in the result 
set? And if so why doesn't it kick in without the **UNION**?

I used to select all from Users, so it should take all the columns from the User table. Then why this exception ?

Comment: Is `MCTD#` your column name in Users table?

Comment: My user table contains `MCTD%23` column which is equivalent to `MCTD#` in ascii representation. Although when I execute single select statements with the same `ORDER BY` sequence, they work fine but `UNION` is causing this problem. However, when I replace `MCTD#` with `MCTD%23`, it works. But why this and not that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the name of your column is `MCTD%23`, then you must use exactly that name to refer to the column.
`%` escapes are a feature of the HTTP protocol and are not used in SQL.

The reason that `"MCTD#"` appears to work without `UNION` is that it does not actually refer to a column. When you are not using `UNION`, you can use arbitrary expressions in the `ORDER BY` clause. If a quoted column name is not found, then for compatibility with MySql, `"MCTD#"` is interpreted as `'MCTD#'`, which is just a constant string value that does not actually affect the sorting.

With `UNION`, `ORDER BY` does not allow arbitrary expressions but only actual column names from the result set, so it is not possible to interpret `"MCTD#"` as a string value.

Comment: Ok Understood but why its only the case with special columns like `MCTD#` that it is considered as a constant string value if used without `UNION`. If I use any other arbitrary column (which does not have any special char like #), then even without UNION, I am getting the sqlite exception `no such column:`

Comment: As I wrote, this happens for *quoted* columns.

Answer (score 2):

2017 Update: If you wrap your UNIONed query in another select, you can use calculated values in your ORDER BY:

```
select * from (
    <query1>
    UNION
    <query2>
    UNION
    <etc...>
)
order by <calculated expression>
```